# MVC3 dropdownlist validation failed for List Type model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dropdownlistfor

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)



        @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].PsfsName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].PsfsName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].PsfsName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].PsfsIAScore)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].PsfsIAScore, new SelectList(Common.Get0To9List()), "Select")

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].PsfsIAScore)
            </div>
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
```

Here I am facing problem for client side validation of dropdownlist, as this is showing validation messages from server side validation. If I replaced dropdownlist to textbox, it show client side validation error message. I cant understand how to perform validation for this.

-- Common.Get0To9List() returns list of 0 to 9 strings & I want to validate if default selected text is "Select" whose value is null.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly assign 99 value(or any other value not in the valid list)  to the first element -select- and then you can specify range attribute over the field. For Example:

```
[Required, Range(0, 10)]
public int SingleSelect { get; set; }
```

Comment: My code shows validation messages, when I used single model. So server side validation is absolutely right. But when I use List of Model to enter multiple values from user, It validate all other values except dropdownlist.

when it goes to server, it validate from server side & show error messages. But I want to validate it on client side first.